# New to SQL Server Triggers

Tags: sql-server, events, stored-procedures, triggers

Let's say I have two tables:

```
dbo.ABC
- name
- address
- city
- state
- zip

dbo.XYZ
- fullname
- address1
- city
- st
- postal_code
```

I want to know whats the best way to write a trigger ( trigCreateNewEntryXYZ ) that

(a) drops the trigger if it exists

(b) recreate the trigger

(c) adds a trigger to dbo.ABC on the INSERT of any new records to dbo.ABC a COPY of the same record inserted to dbo.XYZ

(d) once copied, deletes new entry in dbo.ABC

For clarification, my question has to do with how values of the first table get moved to the second table:

So far I am thinking...

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[trgCreateNewEntryXYZ]'))
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trgCreateNewEntryXYZ]
GO
BEGIN
  CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgCreateNewEntryXYZ] 
  ON [dbo].[dbo.ABC] 
  FOR INSERT
  AS...

END;
```

Do most people move the values using variables? Just curious...

Comment: Your list of requirements looks a LOT like homework. Have you tried anything at all? Start by using google and looking up the syntax for a trigger. We will help you but we are not here as a free code writing service.

Comment: I am not looking for a free code writing service nor am I doing a homework assignment. I am more interested in what is considered best practices.

Comment: Well you would follow steps a and b. Step C requires you to use the inserted virtual table, not scalar variables. Step D is just plain bizarre. Why bother inserting into one table if you just going to insert it elsewhere and throw away the data in your table? For this you would need to use an instead of trigger. I would suggest reading the documentation of triggers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql